# My application terminates saying it has done some unexcepted behaviour

Tags: c#, .net

I have coded he application that automatically submits the data on other 200 sites.

I have more than 20,000 tasks to submit in all the sites.

but after submitting around 10-15 tasks to all the sites it get terminated saying an unexpected behavior.

Can any one help me of about why that might be occurring on the server.

The error which is given is here.

```
Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\WERF10D.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\WERD93.tmp.appcompat.txt
  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\WERDA3.tmp.mdmp
```

Thanks

Comment: Without any code, or at least an proper exception description it will not be possible for anyone to answer this.

Comment: Check what the stack trace is telling you

Comment: Unexpected behaviour on SO if you get answer to this question with the data you provided

Comment: Try to attach WinDBG or VS debugger, and wait until crash appears

Comment: i will attach the snapshot soon as this time it get terminated

Comment: I have added the information about the error. Please check it and help me. Also if possible then reopen the question.

Comment: You still haven't included any useful information.

Comment: What should i include now... I have an application that terminates after running for 6-7 hours and shows this information.

Comment: Was there _any_ useful information in any of those files? Read them, all, and try to figure out what of those files might help others find your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...

How about debugging the application? It will most likely highlight the code that is causing the problem. Also, have you "trycatched" your code? I guess it's almost always a good idea to trycatch it ;).

Comment: No it not giving any problem while debugging, also it works fine for about 2 days continuously.. after that it get terminated unexpectedly

Comment: A program will not crash just like that - it will give a message showing what the problem is. If it just hangs there...then you can simply put a messagebox.show somewhere in your method to show the suspicious code. Most likely the problem is in your...network connection i guess. I have had similar problems when using httpgetrequest among others, and it's always my internet con to blame.

Comment: i will attach the snapshot soon as this time it get terminated.

Comment: I have added the information about the error. Please check it and help me. Also if possible then reopen the question.